# Can the installed APK be over 4 MB in size?

Tags: android-instant-apps

I'm looking for some clarification on the meaning of base, instant, and installed modules.

I checked out this link (https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/faqs) and found that

> The size of the instant app (base feature plus any included dependent
>   feature) should be as small as possible...For an instant app with
>   multiple features, you must add the size of the base feature APK to a
>   single feature APK. The total size of both these APKs must be under
>   4MB.

Having worked through both Google codelabs, I understand the difference between one-feature and multi-feature modules. My question refers to the scenario in which there is only one feature module, the base module.

So, for instance, could the base module be 4 MB in size, and the installed module contain 16 MB more code in addition to that 4 MB to build an APK with total size of 20 MB? Will the Google Play Store accept my app (both as installed and instant version), as long as the instant APK is 4 MB or less, no matter how big the installed APK is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one module that is the base module, that module must be under 4 MB in size for an instant app.

The installed app (APK) can be over 4 MB and can be as large as a standard installable APK can be (I've seen them over 100 MB).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! Figured that was the case but wanted to double check before proceeding.